# Relationship between the word sodium and the word soda

Tags: etymology

I am a student studying chemistry and I am wondering about the relationship between the name of the element **sodium** and the word **soda**.

**For example:** *sodium bicarbonate* is also called *baking soda*, *sodium carbonate* is also called *soda ash*, *sodium hypochlorite* is also called *chloride of soda* etc.

What is the relationship between the two words?

Comment: You should probably ask https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Hachi it is more of an etymological question than a chemical question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *sodium* is derived from the word *soda*.

*Soda* + *ium* -> *sodium*

*(-ium is a suffix that forms names of metallic elements.)*

> **Sodium:** metallic alkaline element, 1807, coined by English chemist Humphry Davy from soda; so called because the element was isolated from caustic soda (sodium hydroxide). The chemical symbol Na is from natrium, alternative name for the element proposed by Berzelius from natron, a name of a type of soda - ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=sodium))
>
> **Soda:** late 15c., "sodium carbonate," an alkaline substance extracted from certain ashes (now made artificially), from *Italian sida (or Medieval Latin soda*) "a kind of *saltwort*," from which soda was obtained, of uncertain origin. Perhaps it is from a Catalan sosa, attested from late 13c., of uncertain origin. Proposed Arabic sources in a name of a variety of saltwort have not been attested and that theory is no longer considered valid. Another theory, considered far-fetched in some quarters, traces it to Medieval Latin sodanum "a headache remedy," ultimately from Arabic suda "splitting headache."
>
> Soda is found naturally in alkaline lakes, in deposits where such lakes have dried, and from ash produced by burning various seaside plants. A major trading commodity in the medieval Mediterranean, since commercial manufacture of it began in France in late 18c., these other sources have been abandoned. Washing soda (sodium carbonate) is commonly distinguished from baking soda (sodium bicarbonate). A soda-cracker (1863) has baking soda as an ingredient - ([**Etymonline**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/soda))

Answer (score 1):

Soda comes from the Arabic word 'saltwort' and sodium (coined in 1807 by Humphry Davy) is a direct derivative of soda.

Comment: Do you mean the Arabic word _for_ saltwort?Anyway, Ety now discounts that theory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a deeper dive into the etymology of "[Sodium](https://elements.vanderkrogt.net/element.php?sym=Na)", I cannot recommend Peter van der Krogt's Elementymolgy website highly enough (the link goes to his page for Sodium).
The gist, as the other answers indicate, is that Sir Humphrey Davy named "sodium" for "soda", specifically "caustic soda". "Soda" as a term, meanwhile, had come to be associated with any of a variety of mineral alkaline salts that mostly, and coincidentally, contained sodium.
When chemistry advanced to the point that we could distinguish between sodium and potassium salts, "soda" was used to refer to sodium salts, even after sodium was isolated and named, whence "bicarbonate of soda", another term for baking soda.
Potassium, meanwhile, was named by Davy from "potash", a vegetable alkali salt similar to soda ash, except is has potassium instead of sodium.